# WebSphere application (V 8.5.5.0) to SQL Server 2016 Database Connection Error

Tags: sql-server-2016, websphere-8

I am trying to connect WebSphere application (V 8.5.5.0) to SQL Server 2016 Database (installed on - OS Windows Server 2016 DC) and getting following error:

> The test connection operation failed for data source Test 213 on
>   server server1 at node C1Node01 with the following exception:
>   java.sql.SQLException: The driver could not establish a secure
>   connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
>   encryption. Error: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array
>   index out of range: 64". DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 0.
>   View JVM logs for further details.

We have set Force encryption as False in Sql Server 2016. Also, latest Sqljdbc4-3.0.jar is used for DB connections. I am connecting on default port 1433.

We are using Java 6 at websphere.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug.  Please report a case with IBM support to have it fixed.